# Waiting for lambda Initialization

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I have some initialization i would like to do outside of my lambda event handling method, mostly just loading environment variables but some of them are encrypted with KMS so i need to decrypt them but i have to wait for the `Promise` to resolve. Javascript isn't my primary language so i'm not to sure on a sensible way (if any) of achieving this.

My current implementation looks like this

```
const controller = parseEnv(process.env).then((parsedEnv) => {
    return new InstallController(parsedEnv);
});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const install = await controller;
    return install.handle(event, context, callback);
};
```

ideally I would like to move `const install = await controller;` outside of the `exports.handler` function. Can I do this without using a hardcoded sleep?

Answer (score 2):

Lambda has been designed for `serverless` architecture, this mean a lambda function maybe go to "sleep" if does not have any invoking.

Then, if you call your lambda function consecutive, variables outside of handler have been cached.

I will show you the way I am on:

```
const initInstall = async () => {
  const parsedEnv = await parseEnv(process.env);
  return new InstallController(parsedEnv);
};

let install = null;

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  if (!install) {
    install = await initInstall();
  } else {
    // Hit from "cache"
  }
  return install.handle(event, context, callback);
};
```

I refactor `const controller` to `initInstall` function, it is a async function.

And create a variable what called `install` to "cache" `InstallController` object.

In `handler` function, just check `install` is existed or not, if not, assign the result of `initInstall` to `install`.

Comment: This is just a more verbose way of doing what i was already doing though right? In my example `const controller` would be a promise that will always exist after a cold start and `await controller` will resolve immediately after the first invocation of the lambda.